# QEMU Memory Allocation Issue

Tags: linux, memory, x86-64, qemu, mmap

I seem to have encountered an issue with qemu memory allocation.

```
static void *
x64_syscall_mmap(void *base_addr, u64 size, u32 memory_protection, 
                u32 mapping_visibility, s32 fd, u64 fd_offset)
{
  s64 result = 0;
  __asm__ __volatile__("mov r10, %5\n"
             "mov r8, %6\n"
             "mov r9, %7\n"
             "syscall"
              : "=a" (result)
              : "a" (9), 
                "D" ((u64)base_addr),
                "S" (size),
                "d" ((u64)memory_protection),
                "r" ((u64)mapping_visibility),
                "r" ((u64)fd),
                "r" (fd_offset)
              : "r10", "r8", "r9", "r11", "rcx", "memory");

  void *sys_result = (void *)((u64)result);
  if ((u64)result >= (u64)(-MAX_ERRNO)) {
    breakpoint();
    sys_result = NULL;
  }

  return sys_result;
}


typedef struct {
  void* base;
  u64 size;
  u64 used;
} X64MemArena;

static X64MemArena platform_mem_arena = {0};

static s32
x64_mem_arena_init(X64MemArena *mem_arena, u64 size)
{
  mem_arena->base = x64_syscall_mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
          MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (mem_arena->base == NULL) {
    breakpoint();
  }
  // I tried without this call, gives same result
  if (x64_syscall_mlock(mem_arena->base, mem_arena->size) < 0) {
    breakpoint();
  }

  mem_arena->used = 0;
  mem_arena->size = size;

  return 0;
}
// ...
// used here 
if (x64_mem_arena_init(&platform_mem_arena, 1024 * 1024 * 200) == -1) {
  breakpoint();
}
```

Run with
`qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 512M -s -S -drive format=raw,file=ker.img -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic -append "root=/dev/sda init=/sbin/x64-ker nokaslr"`

When I inspect the contents of `(u8 *)platform_mem_arena.base`  in debugger I get `0xd6ad000 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xd6ad000>`
In the qemu window I get a line: `x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found`. Could this be something to do with it?

Running on my Ubuntu host it works fine. Memory is valid and zeroed. So, it seems to be an issue with qemu.

Comment: Linux under qemu returns success from `mmap`, I assume?  It's a 200MiB mapping in a VM with 512MiB total memory, but even if physical ram was tight, overcommit should let it succeed.

Comment: Note that you can use `register u32 map_vis asm("r10d") = mapping_visibility;` to force `"r"` to pick R10.  Also, there's no reason to cast args to `u64`.  Any possible high garbage in the full 64 bit registers is safely ignored by the kernel, because its C functions use the same prototype.  Also, `9` can be `__NR_mmap` from `<asm/unistd.h>`.  Or just use https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support/blob/master/linux_syscall_support.h instead of writing your own wrappers.

Comment: `x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.` sounds fine, just checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX to see if there are any write+exec pages (which could be vulnerable to code-injection attacks, if any exploit could write them.)

Comment: @PeterCordes *1:* Yes `mmap` suceeds. *2:* If I don't cast `u32` to `u64` for "r" specifier I get `error | unsupported instruction 'mov'` as an assembler message.

Comment: @PeterCordes Somewhat unrelated, but `qemu` is frustratingly temperamental. Often times I get `kernel panic: not syncing unable to use sbin/x64-ker` which is solved by seemingly blind luck with me just restarting `qemu` until it works. I mention this as I feel it could be possible something not directly related is having an affect here.

Comment: Oh, yes if you skip my first suggestion and keep a `mov`  inside the asm template instead of telling the compiler where you want your inputs in the first place (with `register ... asm`), obviously you need to match the sizes.  e.g. `mov r10d, %[map_vis]`.

Comment: You are using mem_arena->size in the call to mlock() before you have set it to size later in that function. Is that correct?

Comment: @penguin359 You're right that it's incorrect. However, it's non-fatal as the struct is zeroed. I've also removed this call altogether and still get the same issue.